# how to synchronize sqlite database with Core Data?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have an application live in app store which stores data in sqlite database locally. Now I want to use core data in the latest version, how can i be able to sync sqlite data with core data and continue my application using core data?
consider if a user opened the application then his data should be synced with iCloud data and no disturbance should be occurred to the user while using the application.

Comment: make a simlar schema in coredata and migrate all rows of sqlite in coredata

Answer (score 0):

```
self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"revampadhocdb.sql"];
NSString *adhocquery = @"select * from revampadhoctable";

NSArray *adhoctemp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:adhocquery]];
NSLog(@"adhoc Databse%@",adhoctemp);

//From Adhoc Database fill some data
for (int i=0; i<adhoctemp.count; i++) {

    DigitalConatct *dgContact=[[DigitalConatct alloc] init];
    [dgContact setDgName:[[adhoctemp objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1]];
    [dgContact setBirthDate:[[adhoctemp objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2]];
    [dgContact setContactUrl:[[adhoctemp objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3]];
    [dgContact setDgtype:@"Adhoc"];
    [dgContact setDigitalImage:nil];
    [dgContact setSubType:@"Person"];
    [dgContact setSubTypeName:[[adhoctemp objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:4]];
    [dgContact setSubTypeDesc:[[adhoctemp objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:5]];
    [dgContact setSummary:[[adhoctemp objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:6]];
    [dgContact setDg_ID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[adhoctemp objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] intValue]]];


    [self insertNewDAObject:dgContact];
}

#pragma mark insert
- (DAContact *)insertNewDAObject:(DigitalConatct *)daDemo
{   
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
DAContact *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DAContact" inManagedObjectContext:context];

newDevice.dgcontact=daDemo;
newDevice.active=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
newDevice.type=daDemo.dgtype;
newDevice.dgname=daDemo.dgName;

// Save the context.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return newDevice;

}
```

make a simlar schema in coredata and migrate all rows of sqlite in coredata .Below is example where i have migrated all rows of revampadhoctable to core data and inserted manually

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to do it yourself. As in, write your own custom code that

- Reads data from your current SQLite file
- Writes it to a new Core Data persistent store

Core Data can use SQLite but its schema won't be the same as you used in your SQLite file, so this is really the only way.

This assumes that you actually mean you want to do a one-time move of the data from your SQLite file to Core Data. That's what your question describes, even though your subject line says "synchronize". Keeping two different copies of the data in sync is a much more complex problem.